# Changing Gtk.Label.Text does not always work

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a Gtk.Menu with 4 MenuItems. The following code is executed every second to change the Label.Text of each MenuItem:

```
double d = new Random().NextDouble();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ((Label)((MenuItem)menu.Children[i]).Child).Text = d.ToString();
}
```

*I am using mono 2.10.8.1 with monodevelop 3.0.3.2 on ubuntu linux.*

**the issue**

The problem is that not all Labels are getting updated (sometimes only the first and the second, sometimes only the first and the last).

**my quick hack**

I can overcome this issue by letting the thread sleep for 1 ms in each loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ((Label)((MenuItem)menu.Children[i]).Child).Text = d.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(1); // HACK !!!
}
```

**questions**

1. What is the reason for this issue?
2. What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are updating the *GUI* fron outside of the *main GTK thread*.

The *main GTK thread*, who owns the event loop, is created when you call *Gtk.Application.run* .

Several methods are avalaible for updating, you could try *Gtk.Application.Invoke*,

```
 Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {
         double d = new Random().NextDouble();

         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
             ((Label)((MenuItem)menu.Children[i]).Child).Text = d.ToString();
         }
    });
```

This [link](http://www.mono-project.com/Responsive_Applications) could be of interest.